# How to dynamically create a c++ array with known 2nd dimension?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function:

```
void foo(double[][4]);
```

which takes a 2d array with 2nd dimension equal to 4. How do I allocate a 2d array so that I can pass it to the function? If I do this:

```
double * arr[4];
arr = new double[n][4];
```

where n is not known to the compiler. I cannot get it to compile. If I use a generic 2d dynamic array, the function foo will not take it.

Comment: why you don't you a std::vector? array is just c not c++

Comment: @Android400 vector is not alternative to old style array.. std::array is

Comment: When in doubt, use a vector. Solves all the headaches of dealing with arrays directly.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I know but the size isn't static. So a vector could be also a possilbe solution whitout a big overkill.

Comment: @Android400 yes in that case. but since The OP has a function that needs array I saw the vector as not an option.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi vector is almost always an option (certainly not always the best)

Answer (score 4):

As asked, it is probably best to use a `typedef`

```
 typedef double four[4];
 four *arr;     // equivalently double (*arr)[4];
 arr = new four[n];
```

Without the `typedef` you get to be more cryptic

```
double (*arr)[4];
arr = new double [n][4];
```

You should really consider using standard containers (`std::vector`, etc) or containers of containers though.

Answer (score 2):

```
 typedef double v4[4];
 v4* arr = new v4[n];
```

Consider switching to arrays and vectors though.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may not be what OP has intended to do, but it may help others that need a similar answer.

You are trying to make a dynamic array of statically success array. The STL got your solution: `std::vector` and `std::array`

With these containers, things are easy easier:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> foo;

// Allocate memory
foo.reserve(8);

// Or instead of 8, you can use some runtime value
foo.reserve(someSize);

// Or did not allocated 8 + someSize, but ensured
// that vector has allocated at least someSize

// Add entries
foo.push_back({1, 2, 3, 4});

// Looping
for (auto&& arr : foo) {
    arr[3] = 3;
}

// Access elements
foo[5][2] = 2;
```

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively to creating a new type and occupying a symbol, you can create a pointer to pointer, and do it like that:

```
double **arr = new double*[j];
for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
{
    arr[i] = new double[4];
}
```

whereas `j` is the `int` variable that holds the dynamic value.
I've written a simple code that shows it working, check it out [here](http://ideone.com/oLkwuc).